# Is A Table Linking a Dimension to a Fact table, a Dimension of a Fact?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

In my incomplete view of BI tables, a Fact table represents action and a dimension an entity.

I have a `FactOrder` table that contains order information (including *OrderId* and *CustomerId*). There is a separate dimension for people who are actually connected to the order but are not customers. So they are saved in a separate table called `DimServiceUser`. A linking table connects an `Order` to a `ServiceUser`. Should this intermediate *OrderServeruser* table be defined as a Dimension, a Fact or another type?

Comment: It seems to me that the table represents the fact that a service user "served" an order, is it right ?

Comment: @gtosto no, a service user is merely a type of user that is not a customer. e.g. you buy insurance for yourself and have people in your household as coinsured.

Comment: @gtosto the question concerns the middle table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is more of a bridge table. Here's what is going on.

Your FactOrder table is a fact table, but it also contains a [degenerate dimension](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/06/design-tip-46-another-look-at-degenerate-dimensions/). A degenerate dimension acts as a dimension key in the fact table, however does not join to a corresponding dimension table because all its interesting attributes have already been placed in other analytic dimensions. So you have an implied DimOrder in there that didn't require a separate table.

A [bridge table](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/02/design-tip-142-building-bridges/) can connect a set of values to a single fact table row, or it can connect two dimensions (such as customers and bank accounts). It is a way of handling legitimate many-to-many relationships.  A bridge table is [like a factless fact table](http://blog.chrisadamson.com/2011/10/are-bridge-tables-really-fact-tables.html). But in dimensional modeling we do not join fact tables together, whereas it is acceptable to join bridge tables and fact tables together. If you must force your bridge table into being a fact or dimension, it is closer to a fact table. But doing so may make it easier to implement bad modeling habits in the future. If you can call it a bridge instead, I would just go with that. (Make sure you read that third link on "like a factless fact table". It was written by the author of Star Schema: The Complete Reference. That is a pretty well accepted source.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I prefix it with "Bridge-"?

Comment: Prefixing with Bridge is what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

As OrderService does not contain any facts/measurements therefore you cannot call it a fact table.

Dimension table:
A dimension table contains dimensions of a fact.
They are joined to fact table via a foreign key.
Dimension tables are de-normalized tables.
The Dimension Attributes are the various columns in a dimension table
Dimensions offers descriptive characteristics of the facts with the help of their attributes
No set limit set for given for number of dimensions
The dimension can also contain one or more hierarchical relationships

Based on the above definition of dimension table, I believe you table should be referred as dimension table.

Comment: So, even though this intermediate table does not define an entity and works as a bridge between a fact (Order) and another dimension (DimServiceUser), it should still be treated as a Dimension and it falls in no 3rd category?

Comment: This table is reference to collection information about a measurable event, this table is actually just an extension of DimServiceUser.

Comment: But it's a many-to-many table. Still do you think it's an extension?

Comment: What do u want to call it?

Comment: My concern is not what to call it, rather the prefix Dim-, Fact- or something else.

Comment: I got ur point, then u should not call it a fact or a dimension, actually its a union of ur fact and dimension

Comment: Fine. Is there a prefix for such tables?

Comment: It's a "bridge" table; bridge table is a special type of fact tables ("factless" fact table), where fact is implicit (the existance of relations). I wrote an aswer that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392376/how-to-handle-bridge-table-in-star-schema/54490441#54490441

Comment: It's not correct to say that when a table "does not contain any facts/measurements therefore you cannot call it a fact table", a factless fact table will have no measures but is still useful to record facts: https://www.kimballgroup.com/2011/04/design-tip-133-factless-fact-tables-for-simplification/

Answer (score -1):

OrderServeruser table should be prefix with "bridge".

Comment: Care to elaborate why?